# How to use environment variable in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, environment-variables

I just want to few config variables / API urls based on environment like local, stage, production.

I have tried with below tutorial. But I am missing something.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html

Is there any step by step tutorial to achieve this ?

Early response appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything is already in that manual you have posted.

Comment: @Petr Joachim : Yes.. Everything is there.. So only I said I am missing something. I dont know what I am missing.

Comment: There is an exact section called ["Environment-specific system configuration"](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#environment-specific-system-configuration), so I suggest you tried to read that first. If you do not understand it, or your code does not work, then you get back to SO. Now you're just asking to get a rewritten version of the manual, while it's already written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well for me i have 2 enviroment `development`, `production` so first thing i do is to set which enviroment i want to work on it, i do this by configure `.htaccess` file that located in `/public/` like this `SetEnv "APP_ENV" "development"`. 
now i need to show/hide zendDeveloper Toolbar according to enviroment, so i edit the `application.config.php` like this:

```
$env = getenv('APP_ENV') ?: 'production';
if ($env == 'development') {
    $modules[] = 'ZendDeveloperTools';  
}
```

i hope it helps